# How can I deploy a C# application using Ansible?

Tags: c#, ansible

I am trying to explore application deployment tools and came across ansible. Now I have a simple C# console application that I want to deploy on target machine (maybe install as well since it's a console application, or host on IIS in case of ASP.Net web application).

Can anyone please guide me in right direction or some helpful links to follow?

Comment: If it's just a console app why not just use _ClickOnce_.  No 3rd party agents required.

Comment: That would work for one scenario (console), what if its a web application?

Comment: There is also a builtin solution to publish a web application

Comment: Yes there is but my team is exploring devops right now and want to automate as much as possible. I am using jenkins and it can get project from github, build it, run test. Now the next step is to, through jenkins, make this project available for user (by installing in case of console app and deploying to IIS in case of web application. How i can achieve this?

Comment: _"what if its a web application"_ - then use WebDeploy.  Now unless you are also deploying the OS I wouldn't label it "devops" nor do you need some obscure ssh-based solution.  Particularly when you just say build; run and test

Comment: @Monica - how did you progress with this? We're looking to do a similar thing (but with TeamCity as the intermediary)...

Comment: Sorry....for replying this late. For installing window application, i used advance installer (plugin is there in jenkins) for web application, i wrote bat script which will create application is iis using command line, calling pkgmgr utility